# Kafka connect (Debezium mysql connector ) only listening to specific table in table.include.list

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using debezium connector to read data writes in my database and then send it to kafka to be consumed by kafka consumers. I have specified three tables in **table.include.list** but it only listens changes in the first one. Here is the configuration I am using in kafka connect:

```
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
database.user=root
topic.creation.default.partitions=3
database.server.id=184092
tasks.max=1
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=kafka:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=history_dev2.test
database.server.name=test_name
database.port=3306
database.hostname=localhost
database.password=root
topic.creation.default.replication.factor=1
table.include.list=test.t1,test.t2,test.t3
database.include.list=test
```

Comment: Better double check what you post here. Use database.password=*** if you share your config :) I think it looks like a testserver so no probs. The answer of Achyut Vyas seems good to work. Also maybe you need to escape the dot in regex.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add Regex in the **table.include.list** property

Ex.

```
table.include.list=^(test.)((t1)|(t2)|(t3))$
```